# Blurred google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using Google map V2 in my application android ,
I succeded to display map in my 1st application ,with perfect detail ( Zoom )
I used the same code in 2nd application with different API key , i got a blurred map , if i zoooooom out i find the global map with name of continents  .. Help :)

```
private static final LatLng Event_place = new LatLng(33.59648,-7.664723);
    private GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mapevent);
    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(Event_place)
    .title("Hamburg")
    .snippet("Kiel is cool")
    );


    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Event_place, 15));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly some maps types can't zoom after a specific level. Try another map type to see if this happens again.

Comment: I changed the lat and long of location and it work , i rechanged to the last position , and it work hmmm .. I wanna just know why

Comment: Yes I rechanged it to the same first  position  and same map type and it work